# How to store data in Gujarati language in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an Android application for Gujarat's farmers. So this app should be in Gujarati also.

Is there any way so that I can store my data in Gujarati in SQLite?

Comment: Aakash, this question doesn't seems good for this site. And you should explain your efforts. Please read the [FAQs](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) to know the details.

Comment: @Mudassir: hi.. I am just a beginner in Android development and i did not find any thing about android app in gujarati. And for this app i am just in analysis phase so i am checking feasibility if this is possible.

Comment: Aakash, This site is not for technical queries specific to a particular platform. For that you should go over to stackoverflow.com. It is meant for techical queries. Ask your question in a more generic fashion; what is applicable to Gujarati is applicable to any other language.

Comment: That said, I think you can find sufficient information from SQL Lite's documentation itself.

Comment: It shouldnt be a problem - SQLite can handle UTF8 encoded text.

Comment: It should just be a matter of using UTF8 and storing to the database the same way you would with anything else.

Comment: @Mudassir: Akash's question is specific and relevant to anyone who does programming in various foreign-languages. I don't think his question is un-welcome here.

Comment: @Nav: I didn't said its not `specific and relevant` to `programming`. I said it doesn't seems good `here`. This site is for conceptual questions not practical/technical problems/solutions. Please read the [FAQs](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: @AakashRayate: The reason you didn't find anything about android app in Gujarati is, that it JustWorks™. The reason Mudassir is saying the question is bad is, that you should *first try* and only ask if you failed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Just store those strings.

Sqlite always works with unicode strings. Java String is also unicode. So everything should work out of the box. If it does not, than say what that is.

Internally sqlite encodes all strings either in utf-8 or utf-16 (there is a per-database option), but since it always converts them as needed (to one or other for comparison and to/from java.lang.String in the API), you don't even need to care.

Comment: Thanx a lot for this info. Actually i was unaware of these formats like utf-8 or utf-16. Now I've got the idea. Thanx again.